# How to make google place autocomplete results display above input

Tags: javascript, css, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have a text input at the bottom of the page and would like the `pac-container` results to display above the input instead of below as there isn't space.

I can't apply `!important` generic styling as there are other autocomplete instances on the page which need to display normally. I'm using angularJS if that helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for an answer for this: instead of using the google autocomplete dropdown, I created my own by getting an array of five results from the google place data and associated it to the input value of my search. I then selected the name string from the array and built a menu out of it.

```
googleAutocompleteService.getPlacePredictions()
```